# Ver o banco da dados no SQLite

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, android-studio, sqlite

Há alguma forma de eu visualizar o Banco de Dados do SQLite sem precisar escrever o comando na aplicação?
Gostaria de ver os registros inseridos em uma tabela, mas eu não sei se no Android só dá digitando o comando de select na aplicação ou se tem alguma outra forma de ver esses registros da tabela sem precisar entrar na aplicação escrever o comando select e listar em uma tela. Há algum arquivo aparte na pasta da aplicação com o banco de dados criando e de lá eu poder da select ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara, você pode baixar o arquivo para seu PC e visualizar através de um aplicativo como este: http://sqlitebrowser.org/ ou tentar visualizar no android utilizando esse https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kokufu.android.apps.sqliteviewer.free&hl=pt_BR se você tiver acesso a base de dados.